# Unable to pass an array to a second method

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having difficulty with my homework assignment and I'm just not very good at writing code correctly, I can understand how it works but creating it myself is a struggle.  I'm supposed to write an application that creates and array of 10 random numbers from 1 to 100, then print them out.  A second method than calculates the average and a 3rd method displays all of the numbers that are below that average.  I've got the first 2 parts done, but it's only displaying the 10 random ints, not calculating the average, my code is this;

```
import java.util.Random;

public class ArrayTest{

public static void main(String[] args){

    Random random= new Random();
    int numbers[]= new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    int number= random.nextInt(100);
    System.out.println(number);
    numbers[i]=number;
    }
}

public static int average(int [] array){
    int sum =0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        sum += array[i];
        int finalAvr = array[i] /10;
    }
    return sum / 10;
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong, be gentle.

Comment: You never call the `average` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is that you never call the `average()` method:

```
Random random= new Random();
int numbers[]= new int[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   int number= random.nextInt(100);
   System.out.println(number);
   numbers[i]=number;
}
System.out.println(average(numbers));
```

For the third method you will need to loop through the `numbers` array and display the numbers that are less than the average. So something like:

```
public static void lowerNums(int average, int[] arr) {
    //For each int in the array
    for(int num : arr) {
       //If the int is less than the average, print it out
       if(num < average) {
          System.out.println(num);
       }
    }
}
```

Or using Streams:

```
Arrays.stream(arr).filter(e -> e > average).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's how to make an array a parameter in a method:

```
public static void doStuff(int[] numbers){
        //super awesome code
    }
```

If you have an array (called digits) in another method, you can pass it directly to doStuff() by typing `doStuff(digits)`. It's that simple.

Now, for your question.. In your third method, I think you should add two parameters: the array and the average you got earlier. Also, it's difficult to tell how many numbers are smaller than the average, I'd advise you use an arraylist instead of an array. You can convert to an array later. Look at this:

```
public static int[] getSmallValues(int average, int[] numbers){
    Arraylist<Integer> smallNumbers = new Arraylist<>();

    for(int i: numbers){
        if(i < average){
            smallNumbers.add(i);
        }
    }

    return ((int[]) smallNumbers.toArray());
}
```

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!